# Vlookup with Copy/Paste - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, vlookup

I am fairly new to VBA and still finding my way around the codes!

I want to create a **Vlookup** within an IF statement. I want to check the manufacturer first **(Cell B11)**, then using the selected device **(Cell C11)** lookup a range on a separate tab **("List", Range O3:Q11)** and copy/paste the **$ value (Cell P3)** onto the initial tab in a new cell **(Cell L11)**.
As I said I am fairly new to VBA, but here is some code I have attempted:

```
Sub ServiceCosts()

Dim SamsungServ As Range
Dim Manufacturer As Range
Dim Device As Range
Dim MonoSamService As String

Set SamsungServ = Sheets("List").Range("O3:Q11")
Set Manufacturer = Range("B11")
Set Device = Range("C11")

If Manufacturer = "Samsung" Then
MonoSamService = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Device, SamsungServ, 2, False)
ActiveCell.Copy
Sheets("Finance Calculations").Range("L11").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Else
MsgBox "Please Select Device"

End If

End Sub
```

Any help at all will be very much appreciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue with code you have attempted?

Comment: It isn't completing the lookup, it is only copying the Device in cell C11 to cell L11 on the sheet

Comment: VLookup() is an Excel worksheet Function. You probably do not need VBA to achieve your goal; it can be done using just VLookup() and IF() worksheet functions.

Comment: I agree with @AlexBell. Sometimes it is not worth it to automate using VBA but rather by normal built-in Excel Formula.

Comment: I can get it working exactly how I need via an excel vlookup and if function, however one of the Manufacturer Options is 'Other' and I wanted to have further coding to specify that if this was selected, there would be a column which would become unhidden where the user can enter the $ value for the 'other' device. Would this part be done via a code instead? There is a total of 5 Manufacturers and each has around 5-10 devices.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're assuming MonoSamService is the 'ActiveCell' which it won't be unless you specifically tell it to.

Instead, I would do something like:

MonoSamService = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Device, SamsungServ, 2, False)
Sheets("Finance Calculations").Range("L11").Value = MonoSamService

Ie. set the value of the cell in Finance Calculations to what you grabbed from the vlookup.